# Generating discrete legend labels instead of default maximum and minimum label on single bar - QGIS 3.18 to 3.22

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, qgis-python-console, qgis-print-layouts

### Question:

I used a python script in QGIS 3.16 to generate a raster and subsequently a print layout with legends. I am trying to use the same script to build the print layout in QGIS 3.22. However, this seems to have changed in QGIS 3.22, and I get a single bar with two values - the maximum and minimum only. I wish to generate discrete labels, as shown in the first section of the code below.

### Code:

I use the following code to generate the symbology.

```
PT_rlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Depth Colour Scale (m)')[0]
PT_s = QgsRasterShader()
PT_c = QgsColorRampShader()
PT_c.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
PT_colour_array=[]
PT_colour_array.append(PT_c.ColorRampItem(-6.5, QColor('#08306b'), '-6.5 m'))
PT_colour_array.append(PT_c.ColorRampItem(-5.5, QColor('#0a4da9'), '-5.5 m'))
PT_colour_array.append(PT_c.ColorRampItem(-4.5, QColor('#0b6ce9'), '-4.5 m'))
PT_colour_array.append(PT_c.ColorRampItem(-3.5, QColor('#3d91f8'), '-3.5 m'))
PT_colour_array.append(PT_c.ColorRampItem(-2.5, QColor('#79b6fc'), '-2.5 m'))
PT_colour_array.append(PT_c.ColorRampItem(-1.5, QColor('#b7dafe'), '-1.5 m'))
PT_colour_array.append(PT_c.ColorRampItem(-0.5, QColor('#f7fbff'), '-0.5 m'))
# insert array with colours and depth levels into layer
PT_c.setColorRampItemList(PT_colour_array)
PT_s.setRasterShaderFunction(PT_c)
PT_ps = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(PT_rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, PT_s)
PT_rlayer.setRenderer(PT_ps)
PT_rlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

I use the following code to add the colour bar legend:

```
PT_legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(PT_layout)
PT_root = QgsLayerTree()
for layer in PT_layersToAdd:
    PT_root.addLayer(layer)
PT_legend.model().setRootGroup(PT_root)
PT_layout.addLayoutItem(PT_legend)
PT_legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(220, 25, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
PT_legend.setSymbolHeight(6.0)
PT_legend.setSymbolWidth(6.0)
PT_legend.adjustBoxSize()
```

### Screenshots:

Screenshot of the symbology generated in QGIS 3.22
[image: Layer Symbology generated in QGIS 3.22]

Screenshot of the legend generated in the print layout QGIS 3.22
[image: Legend in print layout].

I would like the legend display more like what is shown below
[image: Print Layout in QGIS 3.16].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Symbology menues in 3.16 and 3.22 I noteced there's a new menu-point in 3.22: under `Properties > Symbology > Legend Settings ...` you can now choose **`Use continuous legend`** This is the default setting for 3.22. Under 3.16, where this menue did not exist at the same location the default setting was as if this check box was not activated.
You will need to reflect this in your code accordingly.
[image]

The change it results in is just as you describe:

- **With** `Use continuouse legend`

[image]

- **Without** `Use continuouse legend`

[image]

In the [documentation](https://api.qgis.org/api/3.22/classQgsColorRampLegendNodeSettings.html#a83c32a3856c55db55de910e2d3e85913)
check out the option `setUseContinuousLegend()`. This may be, what you need.

Comment: Excellent, right on target! Thank you.

Comment: I attempted to use the following lines to implement it,
`PT_legend_ramp = QgsColorRampLegendNodeSettings()
PT_legend_ramp.setUseContinuousLegend(True)
PT_legend_ramp.setOrientation(1)
PT_legend_ramp.setSuffix(' m')`
It doesn't throw an error; however, it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can I please get your support here @Vincé